# Error reading using DatabaseContext with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mvvm

I've never had to get this deep in trying to debug an error before so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Running an app in Asp.Net Core 6, C#.
I have no issue with this line

```
var vName = DatabaseContext.Venue.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == viewModel.Name).Name;
```

I have no issue with this line.  I know it will return the record, but that's fine.

```
    var vcEmail = DatabaseContext.VenueContact.FirstOrDefault(
            m => m.VenueId == viewModel.Id &&
                 m.ContactEmail == viewModel.ContactEmail);
```

However, executing this line (similar to the vName return above)

```
    var vcName = DatabaseContext.VenueContact.FirstOrDefault(
            m => m.VenueId == viewModel.Id &&
                 m.Display == vcDisplay).Display;
```

gives me an error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.
vcDisplay contains a valid value.  Display is in the data table/model and viewModel.Id is valid (it was used in the statement prior).

How do I determine what the error is?
Is it that you can't return a value if you use multiple conditions?

_HResult is -2147467261
_COMPlusExceptionCode is -532462766

TIA

Comment: If you are using EF your where statement should be translatable to SQL... SQL knows nothing about your c# objects

Comment: `FirstOrDefault`, returns `null` if record not found.  For sure you will have such exception when accessing property value from `null`.  Replace with `First` and you will get `Sequence contains no elements` exception.

Comment: `vcDisplay` is an object instead of a value? Why you use the whole object as condition in ef core?

Comment: @Xinran, vcDisplay is a variable I created for the search.

Comment: @svytoslaw, I want/prefer it to return null if the record is not found.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying a number of variations, it seems that if the search is going to return a null value, having it return the specific field, like below, throws the error.
I don't see why a null value couldn't still be returned.

```
var vcName = DatabaseContext.VenueContact.FirstOrDefault(
  m => m.VenueId == viewModel.Id && m.Display == vcDisplay
).Display;
```